# Node.js / Express routing

Tags: node.js, routes, express

I'm new to Express. The way I'm doing my routing is kicking back an error.

Here is my relevant code:

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , firebase = require('firebase');

...

// Routing
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/play', routes.play);
```

index.js and play.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('views/index.html');
};

exports.play = function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('views/play.html');
};
```

This is the error:

> Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

It references this line in app.js

```
app.get('/play', routes.play);
```

I'm lost as to why this doesnt work because the code structure is identical for routing to my index page and the index page loads perfectly.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Is `routes.js` in your current directory?  Throw a quick line prior to initializing express checking if `routes` is `undefined` or not.  Could just be a pathing problem.

Comment: @Joe yeah the pathing is correct as far as I tell. It loads index.js (and then index.html) just fine. The location for play.js and play.html is the same as for index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is probably that `routes.play` is `undefined` when a `function` is expected.

```
console.log(typeof routes.play); // ...
```

If your `routes` are split into multiple files as at least the comment, "*index.js and play.js*," suggests:

```
// routes/index.js
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('views/index.html');
};
```

```
// routes/play.js
exports.play = function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('views/play.html');
};
```

Requiring a directory will normally only [include the `index.js`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules). So, you'll still need to `require('./play')` yourself somewhere.

1. You can either "forward" it within `index.js`:

   ```
   exports.index = function(req, res){
     res.sendfile('views/index.html');
   };

   var playRoutes = require('./play');
   exports.play = playRoutes.play;
   ```

   Alternatively:

   ```
   exports.play = require('./play');
   ```

   ```
   app.get('/play', routes.play.play);
   ```
2. Or require it directly in `app.js` as well:

   ```
    var express = require('express')
     , routesIndex = require('./routes')
     , routesPlay = require('./routes/play')
   // ...

   // Routing
   app.get('/', routesIndex.index);
   app.get('/play', routesPlay.play);
   ```

Comment: Thanks man that was it. When I `console.log(typeof routes.play)` it gave me undefined. So I split it up as per option 2. Thanks man, you helped clear it up for me